# Combination for a list of lists of letters

Tags: python, list, combinations

What is the fastest way to get a list of the combinations of a list of lists of letters?
I understand that if the list is full of numbers, I can just do this:

```
randomList = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
for el in itertools.product(*randomList):
        print(el)
```

This would print `[1,4,7],[1,4,8]...[3,6,8],[3,6,9]`
But when I try this with letters, the function just doesn't work. Is there anyway for this to work with letters, or is there another approach to this. I would prefer not to have a function defined.
In short, need something that gives all combinations of `randomList = [[A,B,C],[D,E,F],[G,H,I]]`

[EDIT]-Thanks to the people who answered, I didn't realize that it was registering as variables instead of strings

Comment: What do you mean by "Just doesn't work"?

Comment: You alphabets should be a string

Comment: I do make them a string, but this ends up happening
[['A','B','C'],['D','E','F'],['G','H','I']

Comment: `print(randomList)` -> `print(el)`. Voting to close as typo. Please make sure to provide a [mre] in the future.

Comment: So whats wrong with the above expression? ```[['A','B','C'],['D','E','F'],['G','H','I']``` is supposed to represent a list of lists of strings

Comment: Nevermind I realized that you were right. Sorry. Mistake on my part

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because user typo was why their software didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works, I think you have not given the single quotes for the letters.

```
import itertools

randomList = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
randomList = [['A','B','C'],['D','E','F'],['G','H','I']]
for el in itertools.product(*randomList):
        print(el)
```

Answer (score 0):

It wont work maybe because the randomList you have defined doesnt have alphabets but variables listed as A, B, ...

```
randomList = [['A','B','C'],['D','E','F'],['G','H','I']]
```

Try this.